# Big Oh notation higher than T(n)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have just learnt Big-Oh notation and saw the below problem:

```
(1) Is T(n) = 10n^4 + 850n = O(n^3) ??
(2) Is T(n) = 10n^4 + 850n = O(n^4) ??
(3) Is T(n) = 10n^4 + 850n = O(n^30) ??
```

I have understood (1) that Big-Oh represents the upper bound and hence it cannot be O(n^3) and hence (1) is false.
Similarly, (2) is true.

With regard to (3). Should it be true? If T(n) for an algorithm is say linear, can we also represent it in O(n^2) etc as Big Oh depicts the upper bound ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formally it is true, yes. To represent precise ("tight") bounds, the big Theta (Θ) notion is used instead, whereas big Oh allows the complexity to be lower that stated.
*(If the question requires you to give a single answer, they probably meant the second, though.)*

Comment: Not completely true. There could be functions with no Θ representation (say N² for even N and N³ for odd N). For such a function, the tights bounds are O(N³) and Ω(N²).

Comment: @YvesDaoust , yes, but that same function would fit for O(N^30) and Omega(N), for example. Of course, in practice we are usually interested in as accurate borders as possible, but the formal definitions of Oh and Omega don't demand it

Comment: As you know, I was discussing tight bounds. "To represent precise ("tight") bounds, the big Theta (Θ) notion is used" is wrong.

Comment: @YvesDaoust , I think we're just operating with different terminology here. What I refer to as "tight bounds" is an expression which is both the high and low bound for a given function simultaneously, which is the definition of Theta. What you seem to mean is more like "the assymprotically least among all high bounds for f", which is another (probably) valid, but different concept. According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Use_in_computer_science) wikipedia page, your meaning is often informally expressed by big Oh, which I implied in my italic remark.

Comment: Right, I use tight with the same meaning as in a tight inequality. Θ is implicitly tight both above and below, but it might not exist even though there are tight bounds.